# How to pass and store function into an object, later to be called with a method?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to create a button class that will have a press method, but when the object is created the function that I pass while creating the object is returned immediately. Is it possible to pass functions into objects and store the results to later be called?

```
class Button:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function

    def press(self):
        return self.function


def func():
    print("results")

button1 = Button(func())
#results is printed here
button1.press()
#I want results to be printed here
```

Comment: Briefly: don't call it.

Comment: You're calling it when you pass it in with `button1 = Button(func())`. Don't call it there. In fact, calling it there will make `button1.function` refer to the string `'results'` rather than the function `func`.

Comment: well `button1.function` will refer to `None` in his case since he's just printing

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass in a function, not the output of that function so you'll need `Button(func)`. Inside `press` however, you want to call it: `return self.function()`

Comment: It's working now thanks. I typed the psuedocode up quickly so I must have missed the typo in press. Thanks for the quick fix though. I would upvote your response but I don't have enough 'reputation' lol.

Comment: no worries, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the function `func` not the result of the function `func()`, then call it in `press()` with `function()`

```
class Button:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function

    def press(self):
        return self.function()


def func():
    print("results")

button1 = Button(func)
#results is NOT printed here

button1.press()
#results is printed here
```